# Why wasn't my question viewed by more users?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, tags

I have posted a question, *[Is there a way by which I can complete a PayPal transaction end to end without any interference from the user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18896295/transfer-amount-from-paypal-business-account-to-personal-paypal-account)* and tagged it with `c#`,`asp.net` and `web-services` along with `paypal` and `paypal-api`. The first three tags have a higher number of followers, so they should be viewed by more people.

Also, I want to make sure that I didn't add these three tags for this purpose only, as the question is also related to same.

Where is the problem?

Comment: How do you have 10.6k rep and not know the rules of posting?

Comment: @ColeJohnson with 573 answers and 5 questions, it only requires an average of +2/-1 on each answer.  Even less if you factor in accepted answers.

Answer (score 11):

Well your question is esentially an [`icanhazcodes` question](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/plz-email-me-teh-codez.aspx).  It's entirely possible that the community is simply ignoring it.

Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results in your question.

Also, *titles are important.*  The title of your question suggests a mundane issue with Paypal API knowledge, and doesn't really get to the heart of your specific problem.  Check out the edit I made to the title of your question, which states specifically what your problem is.

Comment: I don't see how the question body itself is relevant to the question posed here. Once someone looks at the body of the question, it counts as a view. This is more a question on titles and tags.

Comment: See my edit....

Comment: @RobertHarvey In my question I am not sure about the right approach or which API are used? So just wanted to know about that and the direction from where should I start. That's why it is without any code. :(

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, more tags seem to reduce the amount of users who will view your post. Specifically, if I don't have experience with Paypal's API, I'm probably going to ignore your post. If your post was just tagged as c#, I might read it; however I still wouldn't be able to answer it.

High view counts don't mean more answers, if anything, low view counts indicate your question is appropriately titled and tagged. However your specific question just applies to a niche group of experts.

The answers will come in time, if an expert can answer it. Don't worry too much about view count.

Comment: I don't agree that low view counts explicitly indicate a question is appropriately titled and tagged. There are numerous parameters which determine why a Q might be popular or unpopular, many or few answers, etc.